# Wordpress get posts with multiple meta values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a ACF select field which takes multiple value. Now I want to use `get_posts()` to get those custom posts. My arguments look like this:

```
$party = 'test1';
$function = 'test1, test2';
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'party',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'value'     => $party,
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'function',
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            'value'     => array($function),
        )
    )
);
$items = get_posts($args);
```

But this does not work! Don't know what is wrong here!

Comment: could you try 'value' => $function . Not 'value' => array($function)

Comment: Tried like this:  'value' => $function which becomes  'value' => 'test1,test2'. Does not work

Comment: I think the approved answer in this post would help you . http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/meta-query-compare-in-not-working